# Why am I getting a strange result with nested for loops?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON data that I'm attempting to process by using some nested for loops. The result I'm getting is not what I would expect. Here is what I'm starting with:

```
data = [
{
    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5589fdbbe1231a40765a71fe",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "5589fdbbe1231a40765a71fe",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Now, here is the code I'm using to process the above JSON:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].days.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < data[i].days[j].items.length; k++) {
            if (data[i].user_id === data[i].days[j].items[k].user_id) {
                data[i].days[j].item_count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log('result = ' + JSON.stringify(data);
```

What I'm expecting is that `item_count` will contain an integer representing the number of items for the current user (given by `data[i].user_id`). Instead, here is what I'm getting:

```
result = [
{
    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 1
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5589fdbbe1231a40765a71fe",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 4
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "5589fdbbe1231a40765a71fe",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 1
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 4
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 1
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 4
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
}
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside, that's not JSON, it's an array of objects. JSON is a string format used for serialisation and data transmission. (The result that your code logs to the console with `JSON.stringify(data)` is JSON.)

Comment: I think that some of your elements in those arrays are wrong: there are TWO "items" properties named "items": I.e. date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "items": 0

Comment: What is the result that you are expecting? can you break this down into a smaller piece of data that has the same problem?

Comment: Does the loop complete, and the console.log() statement actually run with the results?

Comment: I fixed the duplicate ```items```. It wasn't really like that in my code. And, yes I do get a result in the console.

Comment: Seems to be correct: https://jsfiddle.net/e4qxgdg9/1/ ...though when I first ran it in the console, I seemed to get the issue you were having. No idea why.

Comment: I also noticed that if I console.log any particular object during the loop, then I see the correct response for that object. But when I view the entire array after the for loop has finished running, then the results (for all objects) are incorrect. Very strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and the results is right. You might have a cache problem or something like that:

```
  <html>
  <head>


  <script>
  var data = [
  {
    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5589fdbbe1231a40765a71fe",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user_id": "5589fdbbe1231a40765a71fe",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
    "days": [
        {
            "date": "2016-01-14T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-15T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "5608a7b0488505351891c91f"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-01-16T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-08T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "54036a265b2fa765099af857",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b119409736e0086c37ed0a"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "5403cffdbd73cc4e0b49bda7",
                    "item_id": "56b26ff70ac237b50d061578"
                }
            ],
            "item_count": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2016-02-09T05:00:00.000Z",
            "items": [],
            "item_count": 0
        }
    ]
  }
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].days.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < data[i].days[j].items.length; k++) {
            if (data[i].user_id === data[i].days[j].items[k].user_id) {
                data[i].days[j].item_count++;
            }
        }
    }
  }

  console.log('result = ' + JSON.stringify(data));

  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that in my example code. The real code was correct.

Comment: Please review my updated answer. I ran your code and the output was jut correct. Please delete your cache and make sure you are running the correct html code.

Comment: That's strange because I tried the same code in the browser and also on the server (node.js) and got the same (incorrect) result I posted in my question.

Comment: I only see that you posted the result you got when running the javascript. I'm still unable to get it to work correctly, no matter what I try. I've tried it on the client and on the server. I've tried using underscores ```_.each()```, and I've also tried cloning the objects, and pushing then in to a new array. Nothing works. This issue has totally baffled me. It's interesting to me that @squint mentioned having the same issue, but only the first time it ran.

Comment: I just posted my test Code. Can you make your web page public so I can access it from my browser? Please, try the code I just posted and let me know. Let me know also if you can make your page public so I can open it in my browser.

Comment: I'm unable to make the page public, but I just set up a jsfiddle with the exact same code that I'm running locally on my testing server and it worked as it should. But the same code run on my local server doesn't work. For the life of me I can't understand why it works in jsfiddle, but not my computer.

Comment: It turns out the problem was poorly formatted data. I ended up running ```JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));``` on the data set and it worked fine.

Comment: Excellent. I am happy you figured it out !